# Spring @Configuration classes, how to configure multiple instances of the same bean passing different parameters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-java-config

I have a Spring Java Configuration class that defines a bean inside, e.g.:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig{

    private String someProperty;  

    public SomeConfig(String someProperty){
        this.someProperty=someProperty;
    }

    @Bean
    public SomeBean someBean(){
        SomeBean s = new SomeBean(someProperty);
        return s;    
    }
}
```

I need to have several instances of `SomeBean`, each of them configured with a different `someProperty` value.

1. In a Spring Boot application is it possible to `@Import` the same class multiple times?
   **SELF-ANSWERED**: If you import the same @Configuration class, it will override the existing one.
2. How can something like this be done with Spring Java Config?

**UPDATE:**

In XML I can do:

```
<bean class="x.y.z.SomeBean">
    <constructor-arg value="1"/>
</bean>
<bean class="x.y.z.SomeBean">
    <constructor-arg value="2"/>
</bean>
```

I am looking for an equivalent with Java Config

Comment: Look at `FactoryBean`

Comment: I could define `@Bean FactoryBean<SomeBean>` but I still don't see how to specify different someProperty values.

Comment: If you are injecting some bean objects to other beans, you can define it like this;
@Bean  public SomeBean someBean(String someProperty)

So, you'll be defining someBean once and you can create several object by using the same definition

Comment: is prototype scope an option?

Comment: No, there shoud be exactly n instances.

Comment: Where should the values come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to use another @Configuration class that defined as many SomeConfig beans as needed:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig{

    @Bean
    public SomeConfig someConfig1(){
        return new SomeConfig("1");
    }

    @Bean
    public SomeConfig someConfig2(){
        return new SomeConfig("2"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig{

    private String someProperty;  

    @Bean
    public OtherBean otherBeanOne(){
        OtherBean otherBean = new OhterBean();
        otherBean.setSomeBean(someBean("property1"));
        return otherBean;    
    }


    @Bean
    public OtherBean otherBeanTwo(){
        OtherBean otherBean = new OhterBean();
        otherBean.setSomeBean(someBean("property2"));
        return otherBean;    
    }

    @Bean
    public SomeBean someBean(String someProperty){
        SomeBean s = new SomeBean(someProperty);
        return s;    
    }


}
```

Comment: may not be the answer for all items listed on the question, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal but the point is that I need to define someProperty values in config and have n SomeBean instances, without wrapping classes (OtherBean).